# Ember computed properties not getting updated

Tags: javascript, ember.js

if you look at the code below ([JSBin created here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/pibew/11/edit)) you'll see that when I type in the search box the `computedValue` and `aliasedValue` properties should get updated but don't.

**Component JS**

`App.SearchComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    search: 'initial',
    aliasedValue: Ember.computed.alias('search'),
    computedValue: function(){
        return 'computedValue';
    }.property('search')
});`

**Component Template**

`{input value=search}}<br>
search: {{search}}<br>
computedValue: {{computedValue}}<br>
aliasedValue: {{aliasedValue}}<br>`

I've done the exact same thing in a module format using [Ember App Kit](http://iamstef.net/ember-app-kit/) and it works fine. It's just in this context here of using the `App` global that I can't get it to work.

Am I missing something really simple here but can't figure it out?

Thanks,
Pat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

components should be dasherized, so {{do-it}} would be matched up to

```
App.DoItComponent
```

in your case {{search-component}} would be mapped up to

```
App.SearchComponentComponent
```

So it's mapping it up to an Empty component, which is why nothing was working

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vuzozobu/1/edit

Comment: Thanks I'd just discovered this now..feel slightly silly as it was such a simple thing..

Comment: No need, we all have those awesome moments, I extended the router once and was super confused as to why none of my routes were working, router, route, sounded the same to me ;)